# How to rename nuget folder "packages" to "Packages" without affecting solution

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

As per my solution structure i want to changes the nuget folder  from "packages" to "Packages". How to rename nuget folder "packages" to "Packages" without affecting solution.

Comment: You can just rename it? Windows folder names are not case sensitive.

Comment: By renaming directly do we get any conflicts with nuget?

Comment: I see no reason why it should give you conflicts or problems.

Comment: I mean, do we have any configuaration to tell nuget to keep pacakges in "packages" folder? If we have then we need to change the folder name in the configuration also, that's the reason i am asking is there any problem if we only change the folder name.